Tailwind dynamic gap sizes - some are not working
So I have a component that does something like this:
const Col = ({ children, className, gap }:DirectionProps) => {
  const gapFunc = gapClass('y')

  return (
    <div className={`flex flex-col ${gapFunc(gap)} ${className}`}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

Where gapFunc returns gap-x-n. If I tried using different numbers for it, and some of them would work, while others didn't. It seems almost random as to whether a number will work, with some failing. I tested and the numbers that fail could work by manually adding the class name. I am using Storybook, so maybe its an issue with rendering instead? But I wasn wondering if anyone else had some insight into this?

Does this answer your question? Why won't tailwind find my dynamic class?

You cannot directly use dynamic class names like gap-x-{n}. Because Tailwind CSS requires class names to be known at build time to generate the corresponding styles.
But you can just describe the classes you need in a function
function gapClass(value) {
  // gap-x-4 gap-x-3
  
 return 'gap-x-4'
}

